# How can I make sure my lambda runs at the start of each minute

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

I have a [Cloud Watch Rule](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cGkj5.png) scheduling a lambda with a cron expression `0/1 * * * ? *`.
The next 10 trigger dates show that it will run on the first second of every minute which is exactly what I want.

However when I monitor the lambda [Recent Invocations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m17HC.png) (or look in the [CouldWatch logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ed0xq.png)) I see it is always run somewhere around the 37th second of each minute. I am able to adjust this by enabling and disabling my CouldWatch rule again and again until I randomly get a start time closer to start of each minute.

But there must be a better solution than this?

Comment: [Trek10 | How Reliable is Lambda Cron?](https://www.trek10.com/blog/lambda-cron)

Comment: [Lambda with cloudwatch cron trigger only happens 47 seconds into every minute : aws](https://www.reddit.com/r/aws/comments/dzjbis/lambda_with_cloudwatch_cron_trigger_only_happens/)